# Matplotlib defaults the text settings to Greek and I do not want this

Tags: python, matplotlib

I recently re-downloaded matplotlib and the text when graphing is defaulted to greek and I do not want this. An image below shows what I mean. I have never had this problem until I re-downloaded matplotlib.

Plotting a test case.
[image]

Comment: I would start by moving ~/.matplotlib and then debug from there

Answer (score 0):

Try this to configure the settings.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'en_US.utf8')
```

However if you want to check the available languages use the command : `locale -a`

Comment: This did not work. My OS is Windows, so idk if this will work for me.

Comment: I did run the code and I am not having the problem anymore! I restarted my kernel, checked the font (without running the else part) and no more Greek letters. Was this suppose to be a one time run?

Comment: Yes, now that your locale settings are changed, you don't need to change them again.